# How to display metadata schema field keywords value in the content property of tag <meta name="keywords" content=""> in Template Building Block?

Tags: templating, schema, metadata

I have a `Metadata Schema` and it is attached to the page. My meta data schema have a keyword field and in this field value I have a keyword. 
I want to display the keyword value in the content property of `<meta name="keywords" content="">` tag .

I want to display metadata schema keyword field value in fornt of the content property of the meta tag.

How I do this ?

Comment: I think your challenge for your next question should be to properly format it so it is better readable for everybody. You might have noticed that a lot of your questions get edits to improve its readability, certainly around the topic of code formatting. You can find useful tips [here](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [here](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and it is also very useful to just click the `edit` button and see how others have improved your post (what additional formatting they added and how they did that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raj's answer will work if you have a single `keywords` text field in your Page Metadata, if you want that to be a multi value text field (each having a single keyword), you can use something like this in your DWT Template Building Block:

```html
<meta name="keywords" content="<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Page.Metadata.keyword" --><!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex > 0" -->, <!-- TemplateEndIf -->@@Field@@<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->">
```

Note that it is all on a single line, else the HTML will appear on multiple lines too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read this metadata in your Page template's DWT and generate Meta tag on fly.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf name="Page.Metadata.keywords" --> 
<meta name=“keywords” content=“@@Field@@”>  
 <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```